# Django : migration error

Tags: python, django

I have a Django project. Everything worked , until suddenly I got some strange errors like "unknown argument 'pk'". Now I can't run admin, I am getting this error

```
get() got an unexpected keyword argument 'session_key'
```

I can't migrate , python can't understand my models.py changes and when I run the makemigrations command I am getting this error :

```
    Operations to perform:
      Apply all migrations: admin, auth, contenttypes, sessions
    Running migrations:
      No migrations to apply.
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
        execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
      File "C:\Users\kostas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 364, in execute_from_command_line
        utility.execute()
      File "C:\Users\kostas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 356, in execute
        self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
      File "C:\Users\kostas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 283, in run_from_argv
        self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
      File "C:\Users\kostas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 330, in execute
        output = self.handle(*args, **options)
      File "C:\Users\kostas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\migrate.py", line 227, in handle
        self.verbosity, self.interactive, connection.alias, apps=post_migrate_apps, plan=plan,
      File "C:\Users\kostas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\sql.py", line 53, in emit_post_migrate_signal
        **kwargs
      File "C:\Users\kostas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\dispatch\dispatcher.py", line 193, in send
        for receiver in self._live_receivers(sender)
      File "C:\Users\kostas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\dispatch\dispatcher.py", line 193, in <listcomp>
        for receiver in self._live_receivers(sender)
      File "C:\Users\kostas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\management\__init__.py", line 63, in create_permissions
        ctype = ContentType.objects.db_manager(using).get_for_model(klass)
      File "C:\Users\kostas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\contenttypes\models.py", line 54, in get_for_model
        ct = self.get(app_label=opts.app_label, model=opts.model_name)
      File "C:\Users\kostas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py", line 85, in manager_method
        return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
    TypeError: get() got an unexpected keyword argument 'app_label'
```

What did happen suddenly?
Can someone help me please?

Thanks a lot

Kostas

Comment: Can you send the list of your installed apps?

Comment: I didn' touch installed apps 


  `INSTALLED_APPS = [
   'damage.apps.DamageConfig',
   #django apps
   'django.contrib.admin',
   'django.contrib.auth',
   'django.contrib.contenttypes',
   'django.contrib.sessions',
   'django.contrib.messages',
   'django.contrib.staticfiles',
   'crispy_forms',
   'widget_tweaks',
  ]`

Comment: @kpk: Include more information by editing the question instead. There's no real code formatting in comments.

Comment: I didn't change my code. It happened suddenly. I don't know what code to post !

Comment: There's not enough information here to reproduce this bug. There's possibly something weird in the `DamageConfig` app. Try removing it from `INSTALLED_APPS` to check if that's where the bug is. If so, include the model code in the question (click "edit" under your question)  [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

I reinstalled Python and Django and everything worked

Thanks a lot for your time